# Why is my Time displaying 12:00AM in a DateTime Control when in the SQL table the actual time is correctly stored?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am building a simple time clock screen. Employee number is entered; using the FieldUpdated event the employee name is filled out, along with the current time (PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now) in the Clock Time field. Clicking SAVE puts the data in the table and as you can see it is correct. 
Also on the Acumatica screen UPTO this point, the time displayed is correct.

[image: SQL Table]

Upon refresh of the screen the time displayed is wrongly shown as 12:00.

[image: Acumatica Screen]

My DAC code for the ClockTime looks like:

```
#region ClockTime
[PXDBDate()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Clock Time")]
public virtual DateTime? ClockTime { get; set; }
public abstract class clockTime : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<clockTime> { }
#endregion
```

And my event handler:

```
        protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<EMPTimeEntries, EMPTimeEntries.employeeID> e)
    {
        EMPTimeEntries row = e.Row;

        if (row.EmployeeID != null)
        {
            EPEmployee employeeCard = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<EMPTimeEntries.employeeID>(e.Cache, row) as EPEmployee;
            row.EmployeeName = employeeCard.AcctName;
            row.ClockTime = PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now;
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?
Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it. I added to my DAC attribute:

```
[PXDBDate(PreserveTime = true)]
```

Please advice if there is a more proper way, or if this is the way.